# Magneto2 : Add color swatch attribute option with colorcode value programmatically

Tags: magento2, attributes, color-swatches, eav-attributes

I am working on Magento 2 and want to add custom color in color swatch attribute option programmatically. I have gone through [this post](https://blog.mdnsolutions.com/magento-2-create-product-attributes-and-options-programmatically/) but unable to add options

Can anyone helps me to add custom attribute option with color = Black , color code = #000000 programmatically

Thanks in advance. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/351782

Answer (score 2):

#### Step 1

Start by creating a basic setup script for it, if you don't already have one.

```
<?php
namespace Package\Module\Setup;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    const PRODUCT_GROUP = 'Product Details';

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\State */
    protected $state;

    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Repository $attributeRepository */
    protected $attributeRepository;

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem  */
    protected $filesystem;

    /** @var \Magento\Swatches\Helper\Media */
    protected $swatchHelper;

    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Media\Config */
    protected $productMediaConfig;

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File */
    protected $driverFile;

    /** @var \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory */
    protected $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\State $state,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Repository $attributeRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\Swatches\Helper\Media $swatchHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Media\Config $productMediaConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File $driverFile
    ) {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->state = $state;
        $this->attributeRepository = $attributeRepository;
        $this->filesystem = $filesystem;
        $this->swatchHelper = $swatchHelper;
        $this->productMediaConfig = $productMediaConfig;
        $this->driverFile = $driverFile;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.0', '<')) {
            $attributesData = [
               // to add in step 2
            ];

            $attributesOptionsData = [
                // to add in step 2
            ];

            $this->addProductAttributes($attributesData, $attributesOptionsData, $setup);
        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }

    /**
     * Add product attributes.
     *
     * @param $attributesData
     * @param $attributesOptionsData
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     *
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function addProductAttributes($attributesData, $attributesOptionsData, ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup)
    {
        // to implement in step 3
    }
}
```

#### Step 2

Secondly, prepare your data. Replace `\\ to add in step 2` comments from Step 1 with something similar:

```
$attributesData = [
    'fit' => [
        'type' => 'int',
        'label' => 'Fit',
        'input' => 'select',
        'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
        'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table',
        'required' => false,
        'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
        'group' => self::PRODUCT_GROUP,
        'used_in_product_listing' => true,
        'visible_on_front' => true,
        'user_defined' => true,
        'filterable' => 2,
        'filterable_in_search' => true,
        'used_for_promo_rules' => true,
        'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
        'used_for_sort_by' => true,
    ],
];
$attributesOptionsData = [
    'fit' => [
        \Magento\Swatches\Model\Swatch::SWATCH_INPUT_TYPE_KEY => \Magento\Swatches\Model\Swatch::SWATCH_INPUT_TYPE_VISUAL,
        'optionvisual' => [
            'value'     => [
                'option_0' => [
                    0 => 'FITTED'
                ],
                'option_1' => [
                    0 => 'RELAXED'
                ],
                'option_2' => [
                    0 => 'REGULAR'
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'swatchvisual' => [
            'value'     => [
                'option_0' => 'Fitted.png',
                'option_1' => 'Relaxed.png',
                'option_2' => 'Regular.png',
            ],
        ],
    ]
];
```

#### Step 3

Finally, finish implementation for `addProductAttributes` method:

```
/**
 * Add product attributes.
 *
 * @param $attributesData
 * @param $attributesOptionsData
 * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
 *
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function addProductAttributes($attributesData, $attributesOptionsData, ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup)
{
    try {
        // Make sure we don't get error "Area code is not set".
        $this->state->setAreaCode('admin');
    } catch (\Exception $ignored) {}
    try {
        /** @var \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        // Add attributes.
        foreach ($attributesData as $code => $attributeData) {
            $eavSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, $code, $attributeData);
        }

        // Add order if it doesn't exist. This is an important step to make sure everything will be created correctly.
        foreach ($attributesOptionsData as &$attributeOptionsData) {
            $order = 0;
            $swatchVisualFiles = isset($attributeOptionsData['optionvisual']['value'])
                ? $attributeOptionsData['optionvisual']['value']
                : [];
            foreach ($swatchVisualFiles as $index => $swatchVisualFile) {
                if (!isset($attributeOptionsData['optionvisual']['order'][$index])) {
                    $attributeOptionsData['optionvisual']['order'][$index] = ++$order;
                }
            }
        }

        // Prepare visual swatches files.
        $mediaDirectory = $this->filesystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
        $tmpMediaPath = $this->productMediaConfig->getBaseTmpMediaPath();
        $fullTmpMediaPath = $mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($tmpMediaPath);
        $this->driverFile->createDirectory($fullTmpMediaPath);
        foreach ($attributesOptionsData as &$attributeOptionsData) {
            $swatchVisualFiles = $attributeOptionsData['swatchvisual']['value'] ?? [];
            foreach ($swatchVisualFiles as $index => $swatchVisualFile) {
                $this->driverFile->copy(
                    __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'images' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $swatchVisualFile,
                    $fullTmpMediaPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $swatchVisualFile
                );
                $newFile = $this->swatchHelper->moveImageFromTmp($swatchVisualFile);
                if (substr($newFile, 0, 1) == '.') {
                    $newFile = substr($newFile, 1); // Fix generating swatch variations for files beginning with ".".
                }
                $this->swatchHelper->generateSwatchVariations($newFile);
                $attributeOptionsData['swatchvisual']['value'][$index] = $newFile;
            }
        }

        // Add attribute options.
        foreach ($attributesOptionsData as $code => $attributeOptionsData) {
            /* @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute $attribute */
            $attribute = $this->attributeRepository->get($code);
            $attribute->addData($attributeOptionsData);
            $attribute->save();
        }
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        throw new \Exception(__('There was an error adding product attributes.'), 0, $ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, one year before here is the answer:

```
<?php
namespace Hello\Boy\Model;

class Attribute extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{
    protected $eavConfig;
    protected $attributeOptionInterfaceFactory;
    protected $attributeOptionManagement;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig,
        \Magento\Eav\Api\Data\AttributeOptionInterfaceFactory $attributeOptionInterfaceFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeOptionManagementInterface $attributeOptionManagement
    )
    {
        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
        $this->attributeOptionInterfaceFactory = $attributeOptionInterfaceFactory;;
        $this->attributeOptionManagement = $attributeOptionManagement;
    }

    public function processAttributes()
    {
        $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'color');
        $this->registerOption($attribute->getId(), 'red');
    }

    private function registerOption($attributeCode, $label)
    {
        $option = $this->attributeOptionInterfaceFactory->create();
        $option->setLabel($label);

        return $this->attributeOptionManagement->add(
            $attributeCode,
            $option
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add one color option this way:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\AttributeFactory;

class ColorsImporter
{
    private AttributeFactory $attributeFactory;
    
    public function __construct(AttributeFactory $attributeFactory)
    {
        $this->attributeFactory = $attributeFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var ProductAttributeInterface $model */
        $model = $this->attributeFactory->create();
        $model->loadByCode(Product::ENTITY,'color');
        $data = [];
        $data['optionvisual']['value'] = ['option_0' => ['Black', 'Black']];
        $data['swatchvisual']['value'] = ['option_0' => '#000000'];
        $model->addData($data);
        $model->save();
    }
}
```