# Update color visual swatch attribute images Magento 2.4

Tags: product-attribute, magento2.4, visualswatch

**we need to update only images from existing color attribute options.**
[image]

**How to achieve this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Used below code:**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Swatches\Helper\Data as SwatchData;
use Magento\Swatches\Helper\Media as SwatchMedia;

class AddSwatchImage extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_resourceConnection;
    protected $_eavConfig;
    protected $swatchHelper;
    protected $swatchMediaHelper;
    protected $swatchCollection;
    protected $directoryList;
    protected $fileSystemIo;
    protected $fileSystem;
    protected $mediaConfigProduct;
    protected $fileDriver;
    protected $swatchMediaData;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig,
        \Magento\Swatches\Helper\Media $swatchMediaHelper,
        \Magento\Swatches\Model\ResourceModel\Swatch\CollectionFactory $swatchCollection,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList $directoryList,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\File $fileSystemIo,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File $fileDriver,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $fileSystem,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Media\Config $mediaConfigProduct,
        SwatchData $swatchHelper,
        SwatchMedia $swatchMediaData,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resourceConnection
    ) {
        $this->_resourceConnection = $resourceConnection;
        $this->swatchCollection = $swatchCollection;
        $this->swatchHelper = $swatchHelper;
        $this->directoryList = $directoryList;
        $this->fileSystemIo = $fileSystemIo;
        $this->fileSystem = $fileSystem;
        $this->fileDriver = $fileDriver;
        $this->swatchMediaHelper = $swatchMediaHelper;
        $this->mediaConfigProduct = $mediaConfigProduct;
        $this->swatchMediaData = $swatchMediaData;
        $this->_eavConfig = $eavConfig;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $attribute = $this->_eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'color'); //color is product attribute code.
        $noImageIds = [];
        $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
        /* Get All Swatch which does not have image */
        foreach ($options as $optionKey => $optionVal) {
            $swatchCollection = $this->swatchCollection->create();
            $swatchCollection->addFieldtoFilter('option_id', intval($optionVal['value']));
            if ($swatchCollection->count()) {
                $swtachItem = $swatchCollection->getFirstItem();
                if (!$swtachItem->getValue()) {
                    $noImageIds[] = array_merge($swtachItem->toArray(), ['colorName' => $optionVal['label']]);
                }
            }
        }
        /* Download Swtach Image */
        foreach ($noImageIds as $key => $value) {
            /* Get Image name */
            $fileName = ''
            $urlImage = "https://img.buzzfeed.com/buzzfeed-static/static/2020-02/25/19/enhanced/15ddfdbe30f9/enhanced-624-1582658994-16.png";
            $tmpDir = $this->directoryList->getPath('media') . "/tmp/";
            $this->fileSystemIo->checkAndCreateFolder($tmpDir);
            $newFileName = $tmpDir . baseName($urlImage);
            $result = $this->fileSystemIo->read($urlImage, $newFileName);
            if ($result) {
                $fileName = baseName($urlImage);
            }
            /* Set Image Name into temp array */
            $noImageIds[$key]['value'] = $fileName;
        }
        /* Upload temp image into Swtach folder */
        $tmpDir = $this->directoryList->getPath('media') . "/tmp/";
        $mediaDirectory = $this->fileSystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
        $tmpMediaPath = $this->mediaConfigProduct->getBaseTmpMediaPath();
        $fullTmpMediaPath = $mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($tmpMediaPath);
        $this->fileDriver->createDirectory($fullTmpMediaPath);
        $removeImagePath = [];
        foreach ($noImageIds as $noImageKey => $noImageVal) {
            if ($noImageVal['value']) {
                $impImagePath = $tmpDir . '' . $noImageVal['value'];
                if (file_exists($impImagePath)) {
                    $this->fileDriver->copy(
                        $impImagePath,
                        $fullTmpMediaPath . '/' . $noImageVal['value']
                    );
                    $newFile = $this->swatchMediaData->moveImageFromTmp($noImageVal['value']);
                    if (substr($newFile, 0, 1) == '.') {
                        $newFile = substr($newFile, 1);
                    }
                    $this->swatchMediaData->generateSwatchVariations($newFile);
                    $removeImagePath[] = $impImagePath;
                    $noImageIds[$noImageKey]['value'] = $newFile;
                }
            }
        }

        /* Delete Images from temp */
        $removeImagePath = array_unique(array_filter($removeImagePath));
        foreach ($removeImagePath as $removeImageKey => $removeImageVal) {
            $this->fileDriver->deleteFile($removeImageVal);
        }

        /* create swatch image array */
        $swatchvisual = [];
        foreach ($noImageIds as $noImageKey => $noImageVal) {
            if ($noImageVal['value']) {
                $swatchvisual['swatchvisual']['value'][$noImageVal['option_id']] = $noImageVal['value'];
            }
        }
        /* save swatch images */
        if (isset($swatchvisual['swatchvisual']['value'])) {
            if (count($swatchvisual['swatchvisual']['value'])) {
                $attribute = $this->_eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'color');
                $attribute->addData($swatchvisual)->save();
            }
        }

        echo "All Image are Updated";
        exit();
    }
}
```